# how to reuse class containing std::ifstream?

Tags: c++

I have a class A which handles file by opening, reading and closing. I also have another class B that use A to read file. B has instance of A as private member data. I want to reuse the `a` and use it to read multiple files using this instance. I also read some where that we cannot copy any of the stream. So my question is how can I handle class A to read multiple files in B?

```
class A{
   A(std::string s){
      f.open(s);
   }
   void read_file(){
        /// read file

        // close after reading
        f.close();
    }
private:
   std::ifstream f;
};

class B{
   B(std::string s_):a(s_){}

   void read_multiple_files(){
       a.read_file();
        // now lets read another file
       a = A("another_file_1.txt");
       a.read_file();
       ////////////////////
        // now lets read another file
       a = A("another_file_2.txt");
       a.read_file();
   }
private:
    A a
};
```

Comment: Why does `B` need to contain an instance of `A`?  Why not just create an `A` for each file you need to open inside `read_multiple_files` ?

Comment: There isn't anything in your example that couldn't be accomplished with a free function and a local file stream.  That would give you much more flexibility for handling errors as well.

Comment: Have you tried out your code?

Comment: @donkopotamus That was what I was thinking but wanted to make sure if that is an efficient way to go ?

Comment: @vantamula yes its fine ... what "inefficiency" are you worried about?

Comment: @donkopotamus I would have multiple instances of class A object inside read_multiple_files .. causing the stack size to grow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a design issue.  There seems no reason for `B` to hold an instance of `A` unless it needs to keep a file handle across  different method calls.

Instead, simply create an `A` to read each file:

```
class B {
   void read_multiple_files() {
        // read our files
       auto result = A("another_file_1.txt").read_file();
       auto result_2 = A("another_file_2.txt").read_file();
       ...
   }
}
```